# Text over image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a text block over an image, and in the 1st image it works fine, but if I add another div with the same code, the text block of the 2nd image is positioned in the the 1st image.

There is my example:

```
  <section>
        <div>
            <img src="">
            <p><span>Text Example 1</span><p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="">
            <p><span>Text Example 2</span><p>   
        </div>
```

And now the CSS:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

p {

    position: absolute;
    top: 10%; 

width: 100%;

 }

 p span {

    color: white; 
    font: 1.75em Helvetica, Sans-Serif;   
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 0.625em; 
 }
```

I think the problem is related with the absolute position, but I don't have sure.

Thanks

Comment: are you using `id` or `class` to predefined particular `p` or `span`

Comment: show a fiddle for how you doing

Comment: I'm using the same class, and it's necessary to use always the same class, because this isn't for a static website. Is for a  backbone web app, where a user can add 1 image + 1 text block or 100 images + 100 text blocks. So each one of this sections needs to be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zCrQ/

Firstly, keep an eye out on your closing tags, you're missing forward slashes.

```
div {
   position:relative;
}
p {
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:10px;
}
```

The containing element -- in this case the `<div>` -- should have a class of `relative`. The  text you want to appear -- in my example `<p>` -- should have a position of `absolute`. Absolutely positioned elements are *positioned in relation to the first ancestor that has positioning.* This means that the `<p>` will be 10% from the top of the first ancestor that has relative positioning, in this case the `<div>`. If you don't give an ancestor positioning, it will be 10% from the top of the `<body>`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I committed an error in the example that I gave it's a p instead of a div. I think the error may be related with the p Position.

Comment: The element used isn't especially important; the main point is that the *parent element* (the element that wraps both the image and the caption) should have *relative* positioning, and the *child element* (whether it's a `<p>` or `<div>`) should have *absolute* positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You have your positioning mixed up.  You want the div to be relatively positioned and the paragraph to be absolutely positioned.

http://tinker.io/701a5

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}

div {
    position: relative;
}

div p {
    top: 10%; 
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
 }

 div span {

    color: white; 
    font: 1.75em Helvetica, Sans-Serif;   
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 0.625em; 
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I committed an error in the example that I gave it's a p instead of a div.  I think the error may be related with the p Position.

Comment: The type of element doesn't really matter, it just matters which one has the positioning.  Realistically, you probably shouldn't be using divs at all.  Depending on your content, figure+figcaption or possibly article+h1 would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `id` attribute for each `div` and give defferent position

```
div#someid{
  position:absolute;
  top: ...;
}
```

if you want it absolute positioned;

by using `position:absolute`  [the element is positioned relative to its first positioned](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).